# LIKE query in Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

How can I make query, with rule:
order by words, that contain founded string as close as possible to the beginning. Is it real?

```
For example:
search 'hi'
result:
hi all
hi cat
Peter, hi
I come to you and say hi

query = query & Q(name__contains=params['name'])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**SearchRank** is the answer to your question, hope you are using django with postgreSQL, I will not explain as it is well explained in the django docs.
Here is the link to it:-
[Django SearchRank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#searchrank)

Enjoy and rejoice :-)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but your answer must be self-contained and useful even with the link: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then ***quote or summarize* the relevant information from the page you're linking to, in case that page becomes unavailable**. [Answers that are little more than a link are regularly deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). In this case, it would be useful to **show how SearchRank solves the problem**.